# Connecting with Javascript to Web API protected by IdentityServer3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I have a Asp.NET MVC / WebAPI project with an embedded IdentityServer3.

I want both MVC and WebAPI to be protected by the IdentityServer. So I have used Authorize attribute on both MVC controllers and API controllers.

When surfing to my test page (which is protected) I get redirected to the IdentityServer login page. I enter my username and password and get authenticated and redirected back.
On the page I have a button that triggers a GET from javascript, with my access token in the authorization header, to my protected API. But here it fails with a 401 Unauthorized.
I get the access token to javascript by rendering it to the page with Razor.

I have 1 client in the IdentityServer set to hybrid flow. MVC uses cookies, while the API uses bearer tokens.
On my API HttpConfiguration I have set SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication. If I remove that line everything works, but then it uses cookies for the API which I don't want.

I use only HTTP and RequireSsl=false for now to avoid potential certificate problems.

I have tried for days to get this to work but I'm getting nowhere.
I don't even know how to debug this to get to cause of the 401.

By now I recognize just about every page that google suggests when I search for help.

Any ideas what it could be or how to debug this?

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Trace()
            .CreateLogger();

        // MVC client

        string authBaseAddress = "http://localhost:50319/identity";
        string tokenEndpoint = authBaseAddress + "/connect/token";
        string userInfoEndpoint = authBaseAddress + "/connect/userinfo";

        string redirectUri = "http://localhost:50319/";

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "hybrid_clients",
            Authority = authBaseAddress,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,

            ResponseType = "code id_token token",

            Scope = "openid profile roles sampleApi offline_access", 

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            },

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    // use the code to get the access and refresh token
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                        tokenEndpoint,
                        "hybrid_clients",
                        "secret");

                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                        new Uri(userInfoEndpoint),
                        tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();

                    // create new identity
                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.GetClaimsIdentity().Claims);

                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                },

                // Attach the id_token for the logout roundtrip to IdentityServer
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // web api

        app.Map("/api", a =>
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            a.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            a.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                //AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                Authority = authBaseAddress,
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "sampleApi" },
                DelayLoadMetadata = true
            });

            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            a.UseWebApi(config);
        });

        // Identity server

        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "Embedded IdentityServer",
                SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),

                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                            .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
                            .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                            .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get()),

                AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true // Automatically redirects back to the client on signout
                },

                RequireSsl = false,

            });
        });

    }

    X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(
            string.Format(@"{0}\bin\idsrv3test.pfx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");
    }
}
```

My client

```
new Client
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientName = "Hybrid Clients",
                ClientId = "hybrid_clients",
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,

                //AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:50319/"
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:50319/"
                },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "openid",
                    "profile",
                    "email",
                    "roles",
                    "address",
                    "all_claims",
                    "sampleApi",
                    "offline_access"
                },

                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
                LogoutSessionRequired = true

            },
```

My scopes

```
public static class Scopes
{
    public static IEnumerable<Scope> Get()
    {
        var scopes = new List<Scope>
        {
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile,
            StandardScopes.Email,
            StandardScopes.Address,
            StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
            StandardScopes.RolesAlwaysInclude,
            StandardScopes.AllClaims,

            new Scope
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Name = "roles",
                Type = ScopeType.Identity,
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                {
                    new ScopeClaim("role")
                }
            },
            new Scope
            {
                Enabled = true,
                DisplayName = "Sample API",
                Name = "sampleApi",
                Description = "Access to a sample API",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource
            }
        };

        return scopes;
    }
}
```

My API

```
[Authorize]
public class SecuredApiController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        var claims = from c in user.Claims
                     select new
                     {
                         type = c.Type,
                         value = c.Value
                     };

        return Json(claims);
    }
}
```

Part of my Razor view

```
<button data-bind="click:callApi">Call API</button>
<span data-bind="text:apiResult"></span>

<script>
    $(function() {
        ko.myViewModel = new ClientAppViewModel('@ViewData["access_token"]');
        ko.applyBindings(ko.myViewModel);
    });
</script>
```

My JavaScript (KnockoutJS) that calls SecuredApi

```
function ClientAppViewModel(accessToken) {
    var self = this;

    self.accessToken = accessToken;

    self.apiResult = ko.observable('empty');

    self.callApi = function () {
        console.log('CallApi');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:50319/api/SecuredApi");
        xhr.onload = function () {
            self.apiResult(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(xhr.response), null, 2));
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + self.accessToken);
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Katana logs for the API are what you want. With these you will see why the API is returning a 401.

You can access these using the Microsoft.Owin log source (see [Katana Documentation](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging&referringTitle=Documentation))

Comment: I have already activated the Katana log, but unfortunately nothing is written to it when I get the 401. I know the log works, because I got other information there when I investigated another problem.

Comment: Then I think you may need to put code from your API, where the 401 is occurring, into your question. I assume you are using the IdentityServer bearer token middleware which outputs logs to the katana logs.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I have added all the code to my question. Yes, I'm using the IdentityServer bearer token middleware